# Use of brackets in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive

My question might be stupid but I am having a hard time trying to determine whether use {} or {{}} or nothing in my HTML with AngularJS.

I came accross the following :
  1/`ng-src = "{{ mysource }}"`
  2/ `ng-class = "{ active:tab===2 }"`
  3/ `ng-repeat = "foo in foos"`

I think I understand that 3/ is an instruction not a text replacement as in 1/ but why use simple brackets in 2/?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Burger

Comment: 1. is being used to evaluate expression (one-way binding). you can evaluate Math expressions such as {{2+3}}. 2. Like u mentioned {} is an object literal in Javascript and it's not much different here too. Let's put it this way , in first scenario your trying to evaluate a value and in second your just assigning a string based on condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curly braces in example 2 are actually being used to create an object literal (see point 2 [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass#!)) where the keys map to the class name and the values map to the class value. It's exactly the same as the braces used when writing things like this:

```
var myData = {
    x: 5,
    y: 6
};
```

The double braces in example 1 are used for AngularJS [templates](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/templates) where values are inserted into the HTML by Angular.

Example 3 just uses normal HTML attributes (exactly like `<div class="test">`).